# ASP.NET (VB) Trying set DB connection from web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, web-config

I have a web form project to update columns in an Microsoft SQL 2012 database table.  When I "hard code" the connection info for my SqlConnection everything works fine.  However if I try going the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings route I get a keyword 'id' not supported.  I have included the Imports.System.Configuration code into my project.  Below is the Sub where I am running into the issue

```
 Protected Sub BtnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim sqlstring, RqType, RqLast, RqFirst, RqOrg, RqEmail, RqNeedDate, SubFirst, SubLast, RqDetails, RqGenDate, RqOperator As String
    RqType = cbxRequestType.SelectedValue
    RqLast = txtReqLastName.Text
    RqFirst = txtReqFirstname.Text
    RqOrg = txtOrganization.Text
    RqEmail = txtEmail.Text
    RqNeedDate = txtReqDate.Text
    SubFirst = txtSubFirst.Text
    SubLast = txtSubLast.Text
    RqDetails = txtReqDetails.Text
    RqGenDate = txtGenDate.Text
    RqOperator = txtOperator.Text
    If Agree.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("You must agree to the terms before proceeding")
    Else
        myConn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PRRWeb").ConnectionString)
        myConn.Open()
            sqlstring = "INSERT INTO Requests (LastName, FirstName, Organization, DateRequested, DateNeeded, OperatorID, SubjectLastName, SubjectFirstName, Notes, TypeID, Email) VALUES ('" + RqLast + "','" + RqFirst + "', '" + RqOrg + "','" + RqGenDate + "', '" + RqNeedDate + "','" + RqOperator + "','" + SubLast + "','" + SubFirst + "','" + RqDetails + "','" + RqType + "','" + RqEmail + "')"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConn.Close()
        MsgBox("Your request has been submitted.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
    End If
```

Comment: What line does the error come from?

Comment: Show us the web.config entry as well, that is probably to blame.

Comment: This code is a joy for every wannabe hacker in the world. Did you ever heard about Sql Injection?

Comment: Apart from some checking, and correct disposal, this all looks fine to me.
I prefer to use `Using` on disposable classes (including the command).

Comment: The error occurs on the line that specifies the SQLConnection properties.  Also if there is a more efficient/secure way of executing the command how would I go about doing it?  Below is the connection string from the web.config.                                                      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PRRWeb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=rickm-2012;Initial Catalog=PRR; ID=user; Password=password'" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: See a [reference about connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/) It is _;User ID = user;_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by adding a connectionstring to my web.config like so

```
<connectionStrings >
<add
  name="PRRWeb"
  connectionString="Server=server;Database=DB;Timeout=200;User ID=user; Password=Password; Trusted_Connection=False;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And then added this to my vb code

```
myConn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings   ("PRRWeb").ConnectionString)
```